# how to convert Byte[] to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem: I use byte[] to store data, but I have to connect several byte[] togather, I know Arrays.addAll(Arrays.asList(Byte[])) will do the thing, but how to convert byte[] to Byte[], and how to revert Byte[] to byte[]?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, by [edit]ing your question. Also please convey any research that you have done.

Comment: And also tell us what the results were. For example, "I tried this but it gave me this compile error: <specify>" or "I tried this and passed in [1, 2] but I got out [0]."

Comment: If I were you, I'd just do it by brute force--declare your own `byte[]` whose length is the total length, and use loops to copy the data.  Java doesn't always do a good job with arrays of primitive types, and some newer Java 8 features that could help you with some primitive types aren't defined for `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Byte to byte

```
 public class convertByteTobyte {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Byte[] Byte = new Byte[50];
    System.out.println("Byte length is:" + Byte.length);
    byte[] b = new byte[Byte.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < Byte.length; i++) {
        b[i] = Byte[i];
    }
    System.out.println("byte length is:" + b.length);
}
}
```

Convert byte to Byte

```
public class ConvertbyteToByte {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] b = new byte[50];
    System.out.println("byte length is:" + b.length);
    Byte[] Byte = new Byte[b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        Byte[i] = b[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Byte length is:" + Byte.length);
}
}
```